# Como enviar dados de um filtro em php com vários campos de busca

Tags: php, mysql

Estou criando uma página de filtro, mas essa página irá ter muitos campos para o usuário poder preencher, selecionar e isso irá fazer uma busca no banco `mysql` e irá retornar os dados para o usuário em uma outra página.

Uma das dúvidas que tenho, que por ser muitos campos, com campos do tipo select, input's[text, option, checkbox], é se mando os dados por get ou é nesse caso passo por post?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O melhor é usar **POST** pra esse tipo de ação, principalmente se você tiver algum campo do tipo *textarea*, onde o conteúdo possa ser muito grande e pode **extrapolar o limite da url** (apesar de não ter um limite estabelecido, geralmente os servidores limitam, e o aconselhável é usar URL's menores do que 2000 caracteres. [Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3091523/3497987))  caso o método for **GET**.

Porém quando não há a necessidade de um *textarea* (o que não vejo muito utilidade em um filtro) e tenha uma boa validação contra *SQL Injection* pode se usar **GET** sem problemas.

Uma boa melhoria para filtros de muitos campos é criar um histórico de consultas e consultas favoritas.

Comment: Então, não é como criar o filtro e sim qual melhor metodo utilizar, pergunto isso pq, eu sei que se eu enviar por get irá ficar na url do usuário e com isso ele pode copiar e colar e consultar futuramente (isso pode ser bom) mas ao mesmo tempo, como vc mesmo disse, se eu tiver um campo do tipo textarea, por exemplo, poderá estourar o limite da url.

Comment: E aproveitando, editei a pergunta, acho que agora fica um pouco mais claro.

Comment: Isso, mas tipo, você pode limitar o tamanho do textarea, apesar de que não vejo muito utilidade em textarea para um filtro, então neste caso pode-se utilizar o método GET sem problemas algum, lembrando apenas de fazer uma boa validação para evitar _SQL Injection_ e _voilá_.

Comment: Ah sim, não que eu tenha textarea no meu filtro, mas sim alguns campos do tipo input[type=text], select>option, input[type=radio], input[type=checkbox] mas são vários de todos esses.

Comment: Acabei de ver em uma outra pergunta, sobre o [limite da URI](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3091523/3497987). Até atualizei ali a resposta.

Answer (score 1):

**Resumindo acho post mais seguro.**

**O método GET**

GET, um dos métodos do HTTP, é acionado por meio de um formulário HTML através da diretiva method=get incluída na tag . Por meio desse método, os dados constantes no formulário são primeiramente transmitidos ao software servidor e este, por sua vez, armazena os dados temporariamente numa variável de contexto denominada QUERY_STRING.

Um script CGI, chamado através da diretiva action= incluída na tag inicial do formulário, precisa extrair os dados dessa variável de contexto para poder obter os dados que lhe foram enviados (veja também variáveis de contexto). Usando Perl, por exemplo, é possível extrair esses dados com $dados_form = $ENV{'QUERY_STRING'};.

Quando um formulário HTML utiliza o método GET, o fluxo de dados é separado do endereço URL que chama a CGI através de um ponto de interrogação (?). Esta forma de endereçamento e separação pode ser observada no campo de endereços do navegador do usuário, logo após o formulário ter sido enviado. Você verá algo como:

http://www.meusite.com/meuscript.cgi?nome=Maria&id=123**O método POST**

POST, também um método do HTTP, é acionado por meio de um formulário HTML através da diretiva method=post incluída na tag .

Este método faz com que os dados do formulário sejam diretamente transmitidos ao endereço que constar da diretiva action=. Um script CGI, chamado por action=, precisa extrair os dados através da entrada padrão (standart input) para poder obter os dados transmitidos pelo formulário. Pode-se, por exemplo, usar Perl e indicar read(STDIN, $Dados, $ENV{'CONTENT_LENGTH'});.

Observe que o programa precisa obter o valor da variável de contexto CONTENT_LENGTH para saber quantos caracteres precisam ser lidos através da entrada padrão. Isto é necessário porque não existe um caracter separador no fluxo de dados.

**A importância de se conhecer o método**

Se você quiser fazer uso de um script CGI pronto, precisa saber por qual dos dois métodos o script espera receber dados. Normalmente isto vem documentado pelo autor do script. Alguns scripts mais inteligentes testam ambos os métodos - neste caso, não importa o método de transferência de dados que você usar no formulário - ambos vão funcionar.

Se você for escrever seus próprios scripts, lembre-se de determinar o método que deve ser utilizado no formulário. Ou programe de maneira inteligente: deixe o script preparado para ambos os métodos.

**Fluxo de dados na transmissão de dados de formulários**

Um formulário HTML típico é composto por campos nominados (por exemplo para nome, endereço e comentário). Na transmissão do formulário preenchido para o servidor web / programa CGI, os dados precisam ser transmitidos de tal forma que o script CGI seja capaz de identificar os campos do formulário e os valores dos mesmos. É por isso que existe um método de codificação específico que separa os campos do formulário dos seus respectivos valores. Este método de codificação baseia-se nas seguintes regras:

. Cada um dos elementos do formulário, inclusive seus valores, são separados entre si pelo símbolo & ("e" comercial ou ampersand);
. O nome e o valor (dados) de um elemento do formulário são separados por = (sinal de igual);
. Espaços em branco existentes nos dados (p.ex. várias palavras) são substituídos por + (sinal de adição);
. Todos os caracteres ASCII estendidos, com valores de 128 a 255 (hexadecimal 80 até FF), são substituídos por um conjunto constituído pelo sinal de % (porcento) seguido do valor hexadecimal do caracter (p.ex. o nosso ç (c cedilha) é substituído por %E7);
. Todos os caracteres utilizados nestas regras como delimitadores (ou seja, &, +, = e %) também são convertidos em hexadecimal seguindo a mesma regra para os caracteres ASCII estendidos.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, mas ainda assim não me tirou realmente a minha dúvida que tenho e pelo que comentou "Resumindo acho post mais seguro." ainda não acho que seja a resposta mais correta para o que preciso. Valew

Comment: Acho que para uma resposta melhor precisamos de pergunas melhores

Comment: Acho que me entendeu errado, mas ok. O que quis dizer é que para o que perguntei eu gostaria de saber outras coisas, como questão de quantidade de caracteres que se podem ser passados pelo get e pelo post, segurança, mas algo mais concreto em relação a segurança, mas ainda assim obrigado

Comment: Agora entendendo um pouco melhor Os browsers permitem até 2kb, ou entre 2000 e 2400 bytes.
O limite depende de cada browser